# How to create a new Database per new user in CouchDB without application Tier

Tags: couchdb

I'm facing the "How to keep private user data private in CouchDB" challenge. Detailed quite well on the couchdb wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/PerDocumentAuthorization

I've chosen to make a new database per user, because that's the best fit for the applications I'm creating and because there's a lot of advice from the community to go that route.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. Is there a built in way to do this in CouchDB? So far I have no other need for a middle tier or application tier, and would love to keep this purely a couch + htmll5 application. What is the best case practise for this?

Answer (score 3):

A [new feature](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=couchdb.git;a=commit;h=d56f2fc4f268c9e750741fa49bf5640cdf09fbdb) will add support for auto creating/deleting a database per user.

The following section will be added to `default.ini` and `local.ini`:

```
[couch_peruser]
; If enabled, couch_peruser ensures that a private per-user database
; exists for each document in _users. These databases are writable only
; by the corresponding user. Databases are in the following form:
; userdb-{hex encoded username}
enable = true

; If set to true and a user is deleted, the respective database gets
; deleted as well.
delete_dbs = true
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following line is the easiest way to achieve it :

```
curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/${user_name}
```

PS : I found it here http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/tour.html

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, I just need to be able to do it on the fly as new users sign up (programatically). One thing that someone described was doing a tiny node app that listens to the _changes feed on the _user db, but I wouldn't even know where to start with something like that. Anywho those types of solutions is what I'm looking for. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: I tried database creation on http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html via postman which failed, then I tried curl and voila ! it worked ! The reason request was failing in postman was that curl by default uses "Basic Authentication" if not explicitly specified. Postman however needs the "Basic Authentication" to be selected explicitly ! = In short, the authentication in the header was the culprit !